# Is there a general right to bear arms in the Federation?

Tags: star-trek, weapon, laws

In the TNG episode "The Most Toys", the [Varon-T disruptor](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Varon-T_disruptor) is specifically mentioned as being illegal in the Federation because of its particularly cruel method of killing. Singling out a specific weapon and saying that it is banned seems to imply that other weapons are *not banned*. Does the Federation have a general right to bear arms for civilians? For example, if a civilian wants to walk across the 24th century Golden Gate Bridge with a Klingon disruptor pistol strapped to his belt for *non-aggressive* reasons (personal protection, because it looks cool, family heirloom, cultural or religious requirement, whatever), is this allowed? If there are restrictions (e.g. stun weapons only unless a civilian weapons license is held, no disintegrators, max battery capacity, must be 21, etc.), what are they?

In Star Trek V, it is specifically mentioned that Nimbus III, the "Planet of Galactic Peace", which is jointly administered by the Federation, Klingons, and Romulans, [bans civilian ownership of weapons](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Nimbus_III), also implying that civilians *not* on Nimbus III *do* have access to weapons (otherwise, banning them on Nimbus III would lack significance).

On pre-Federation Earth, we see an apparently civilian farmer with a plasma weapon (ENT: Broken Bow), so there seems to be some precedent for personal weapon ownership beyond the 21st century.

Comment: I'm feeling like the member planets of the Federation are sovereign states, thus civilian laws would probably change depending where you live. However, since I can't recall any supporting or contrary lore I'm not posting as an answer.

Comment: Aren’t weapons not permitted at all on Risa?

Comment: Given that many advanced weapons seem to have an equivalent of a "stun" setting, perhaps the issue is whether lethal weapons are allowed, as presumably stun weapons might be less problematic for the Feds.  And that farmer might not have been supposed to have his weapon - why assume it was legal - it does seem a bit OTT for a farmer on a planet which we are told has world peace !

Comment: Or the farmer's weapon might have been legally purchased as a."stunner" and later modified for added power. There's too much we don't know about the laws on Earth and in the United States at that time.

Comment: @StephenG World peace doesn't mean no crime or wild animals. In many countries the laws as applied to handguns in the city don't apply to rifles in the countryside anyway. I like the stun weapon idea though.

Comment: Just because the Varon-T disruptor was singled out doesn't mean other guns aren't also illegal. It might be illegal for everyone, even the government/Starfleet.

Comment: *about the laws on Earth and in the United States at that time* Do we even know if the ST universe at that time has countries (as in independent national states) at that time ?

Comment: @zabeus even in the UK it is possible to get a shotgun if you can show that you need it (e.g. you are a farmer or live in the countryside and need to shoot wild animals).

Comment: [The right to bear arms?](https://truthinreligionandpolitics.files.wordpress.com/2013/01/bear-arms.jpg)

Comment: @StephenG it's likely countries do still exist. In TNG *Lower Decks* Sam Lavelle remarks that he is Canadian, and Riker is revealed to be Alaskan.

Comment: @Xantec Seems to confirm it, unless it's a reference to cultural origin, rather than a State.  Like the way some Americans would say they're Irish, even though they were born in the US.  But I'll go with countries still existing in the absence of some other evidence.  Thanks.

Comment: @Xantec Germany is a peaceful country and yet we own weapons like crazy. It's just that they are heavily regulated (no fully automatic weapons, not public carry unless you have a need for self defense certified by the state). But our arsenals tend to be quite deadly, the one thing that is actually illegal are "stunnners" (tasers). So "peaceful" doesn't not necessarily matter to the question.

Answer (score 5):

We don't often see an armed civilian in Star Trek. The earliest (chronologically) was in the *Star Trek: Enterprise* pilot [Broken Bow](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Broken_Bow_(episode)), where a farmer armed with a [plasma rifle](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Plasma_rifle) shoots a Klingon (this was in the nascent days of the Federation)

[image: Man holding a futuristic rifle]

[image: Man shooting a Klingon coming out of a cornfield]

The other incidents I can find with firearms either involve military circumstances (i.e. sidearms or armed conflicts) or some sort of exigent storyline (i.e. [North Star](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/North_Star_(episode)), which involved humans kidnapped from the 19th century wild west).

Either way, it appears that the Federation allowed some private ownership of weapons. Given that we often see colonies [destroyed](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Cestus_III) or face [civil unrest](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Turkana_IV_colony), allowing private weapon ownership seems to be the only logical conclusion for people living on the "final frontier".

The [Maquis](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Maquis) represent the only time we see the Federation try to disarm a group. They formed their own militia when they opted to live within the demilitarized zone between Federation and Cardassian space. The Federation openly tried to disarm them to avoid stirring a war with the Cardassians.

Comment: Technically, the Maquis are not within Federation jurisdiction because of the treaty with the Cardassians, although they are Federation citizens.  In all likelihood, it's actually *Cardassia* which forbade them from possessing weapons.  Very few real-world countries will attempt to defend the right to bear arms for citizens not within their borders.  Add to that the treaty with the Cardassians, which may or may not require the Federation to take such steps, and the diplomatic implications of allowing the Maquis to go unchallenged, and the UFP's behavior seems downright reasonable.

Comment: We do see a Nausicaan armed with a knife in TNG *Tapestry*

Comment: And in TNG *Brothers* there is mention of laser pistols, with "toy" ones used in a game.

Comment: In various gun-restrictive jurisdictions (including the UK) farmers have a special right to own firearms because they need them for their work.

Comment: I seem to recall Kevin Uxbridge having a gun, and no question about it being illegal.