# Why is Guinan allowed to have a non-Starfleet issued rifle?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, weapon, laws, starfleet-command

In the *Star Trek TNG* episode: [Night Terrors](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Night_Terrors_(episode)), we see Guinan using a rifle in order to break up a brawl at Ten Forward:

[image]

In a hilarious [piece of dialog](http://www.chakoteya.net/NextGen/191.htm) she immediately admits that this rifle is not Starfleet issued:

> **GILLESPIE**: What is that?
>
> **GUINAN**: It's a little souvenir I picked up on Magus Three. That was setting
> number one. Anyone want to see setting number two?

While Starfleet is not a military organization, it has similar structures (Captains, Admirals, enlisted personnel etc), so even though Guinan is a civilian, I doubt they would allow her to bring her own weapon on board.

So my question is: **Why is Guinan allowed to have a non-Starfleet issued rifle?**

Comment: Imagine that you’re Star Fleet security, and you’re vetting baggage that the crew are bringing on board. Are _you_ going to tell Guinan that she can’t have her gun?

Comment: Are you going to try to take it off of her?

Comment: Non-canon speculation: maybe she just asked Picard for permission.

Comment: Guinan: "I can't tell you when.  I can't tell you how.  But one day, the fate of several timelines will depend on me having that gun under there." Picard: "Oh... okay, I understand... you can't risk contaminating the timeline by telling me.  Okay, you can have it."  Guinan (to herself): I can't believe he bought that!

Comment: She never says it's a weapon, just lets people believe it is. It might be a toy, literally a souvenir.

Comment: @Gaultheria In the episode she actually fired it and the beam hit the ceiling, scaring everyone!

Comment: @Rebel-Scum — Did it damage anything when she did that?

Comment: She's also the only one on board that has real alcohol, which has actual canon to be against Starfleet regulations. Stop asking questions before you mess that up for everyone.

Comment: Personally, I can't follow the Question's chain of logic.  Why would they object?  At most, they scanned it a dozen different ways. She demonstrated it on a target range to the interested and curious.  Nothing to cause alarm here, carry on.  If non-standard Starfleet weapons cause alarm, then how is Worf allowed to decorate the walls of his quarters with an arsenal of blades?

Comment: And Guinan did demonstrate a very high skill with beam weapons... Poor Worf...

Comment: @Blaze The point is that military ships do not allow crew-members (drafted, civilian or otherwise) to bring their own weapons on board. Now, Enterprise is not a military ship, but it is organized as one, so the question is why is Guinan allowed to bring her own rifle!?

Comment: @Balze Furthermore, it is not clear if said rifle satisfies any safety regulations that might exist, eg having a stun setting, not being disruptor-like (some of these are banned in the Federation) etc.

Comment: I don't really grok the premise of the question. You say you doubt she'd be allowed to have the rifle, but clearly she was. So the doubt is baseless and this renders the question vacuous, no?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Just because she got it on board it doesn't mean it was allowed. Other people have been known to smuggle in Romulan Ale and other forbidden items, so the question boils down to: did she get permission to have it on board or did she smuggle it in? The obvious problem is that if everyone starts bringing in their own guns for safety (space is dangerous, right?), then this would lead to chaos....

Comment: This question here is extremely relevant: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/180178/is-there-a-general-right-to-bear-arms-in-the-federation

Comment: @MikeScott Much more likely you would be transported on board to find your gun nonfunctional

Answer (score 12):

There isn't currently an answer for this in canon, but there is some reasonable speculation that can be made:

- "I doubt they would allow her to bring her own weapon on board." There isn't anything to say that they wouldn't. The Federation may have an equivalent to the Second Amendment of the United States Constitution that says that its citizens have the right to bear arms. Worf is also regularly noted to possess a number of weapons that are definitely not Starfleet issue.
- Guinan has a very close relationship with Captain Picard, so it stands to reason that even if she would normally have been restricted from bringing her own weapon on board, Picard may be in a position to make an exception.
- Guinan is established in "Redemption" to practice regularly on the phaser range. It could be that the rifle is really a target marker that she uses for practice that is incapable of affecting a person, and that she's merely bluffing to the unruly patrons.
- It is entirely possible that she isn't allowed to have it but has it anyway. Romulan Ale also has a way of ending up on Starfleet ships, despite being illegal.